# Can you modify the CSS properties of the parent from iFrame child?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm using iframes to display the contents of another page within my page. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("foo").style.display="none";
</script>
```

But to the parent? IE: Grab an element of the parent and set the style?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

If the pages are on the same domain, yes.

```
<script>
    parent.document.getElementById("foo").style.display="none";
</script>
```